# Storing lots of different String in one variable

Tags: java, arrays, string, enums

Is there an easier way to store multiple strings (which are all unique) in a variable other than an array or an enum?  I want to be able to easily access the string also.

Comment: How would an enum be an option? Why would you not want to use a `Set<String>` or a `List<String>`? Basically you haven't provided enough context for us to help you.

Comment: what is the problem with `Set`?

Comment: Show your code for better help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to store Unique multiple String , Then I guess java.util.Set is a good option

```
Set<String> uniqueString = new HashSet<String>();
```

I hope below example will help you to understand the concept better

```
    Set<String> uniqueString = new HashSet<String>();
    uniqueString.add("test");
    uniqueString.add("test");
    uniqueString.add("count");
    uniqueString.add("check");

    for (String item : uniqueString) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
```

**Output**

> check
>            count
>        test

Here you can find(in output) , duplicate string "test" has been striped out and only unique values has been printed

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an easier way to store multiple strings (which are all unique)

yes there is :

```
Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
```

> I want to be able to easily access the string also.:

you can't access specific index of  `Set`,

you can however iterate through them

```
while(String s : set){
 System.out.println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per these answers, a Set would be a suitable option. If this does not suit you, look into using a **delimiter** instead to separate the strings.